# c# / xaml - Bottom Bar is positioned wrong

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have created a Bottom Bar with the following xaml code:

```
<CommandBar x:Name="combar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="#FF2290AF" SizeChanged="CommandBar_SizeChanged">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Refresh" Label="Aktualisieren" Click="AppBarButton_Click" />
    <AppBarSeparator/>

    <CommandBar.Content>
        <ProgressRing x:Name="loading_ring" Width="48" Height="48" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Foreground="White" />
    </CommandBar.Content>
</CommandBar>
```

In Visual Studio it looks like:
[image: VS_Picture]

During runtime the bottom bar is displayed like that:
[image: Screenshot runtime]

Does anybody know a solution?

Comment: It's placement is relative to content. Would help to see more of the parent layout.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I forgot about that!

Comment: yes agree with @Chris W. post the layout code (Grid, StackPanel) it will probably be a problem there

Comment: You can use `Live Visual Tree` on the left side of the VS to check your BottomBar's properties, find your BottomBar in the Live Visual Tree, right click on it and show properties, you can find if any space in the bottom there.